# The right hand rule confusion?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: he]

I have a question regarding this problem. By using the right hand rule, I thought the answer would be A, but the answer key says it's B. 
Doesn't the current come from the + side, so you wrap your fingers towards yourself(?) so that the thumb points to the left?

Comment: Hint: the current follows the **wires wound in a spiral pattern around the core**. It doesn't go through the core. If you move your right hand along that spiral, with your thumb pointing in the direction of the current in the wire, you should arrive at the correct answer.

Comment: @probably_someone it looks like the OP is considering the current through the coil. If you wrap you fingers around the coil in the direction of current your thumb does point to the left.

Comment: @AaronStevens But the current in the coil _doesn't_ point directly to the left, it follows a helix that gradually spirals to the left. This distinction is crucial toward getting the right magnetic field direction with the right-hand rule - just follow the helix with your thumb for one turn and you should be able to see the magnetic field direction from the way your fingers are pointing in the center of the loop.

Comment: @probably_someone The OP is probably using/asking about [this RHR](https://images.app.goo.gl/AAkSnJsboURxzAdY6). Which can be "derived" from the RHR you are talking about.

Comment: @probably_someone I know that the current follows the wire wound in a spiral pattern. Like the picture that you hyperlinked, if you wrap around your finger in the direction of the wire, the thumb should face the left, right? Then how could the answer be B?

Answer (score 1):

Electric and magnetic fields are best understood using the terminology "electric field ${\bf E}$" and "magnetic field $\bf B$". In the case of a magnetic field this is better terminology than "lines of force" because the force produced by a magnetic field on a small object such as a current-carrying wire or a moving charge is perpendicular to the field not along it. And when a small magnet such as a compass is placed in a magnetic field, the effect of the magnetic field is to align the compass without producing any net force on it in any direction (it just produces a torque until the small magnet is aligned with the field). Therefore I will avoid the term "line of force" in my answer. I will call them "field lines" or "lines of magnetic field".

In the case of a straight current-carrying wire, the magnetic field loops around the wire in a right-handed direction. That is, if you make your right thumb point along a current then the curled fingers of your right hand show the magnetic field direction. If you do this for each small section of a current-carrying loop, then you find that the field through the middle of the loop has to be in the direction given by your right thumb when your right hand fingers curl around the loop. The current in the circuit shown in the question goes from $+$ to $y$ to $x$ to $-$ so we deduce that the magnetic field lines (lines of $\bf B$) go from $y$ to $x$ inside the coil, and then loop around outside till they come back to $y$.

The terminology "north pole, south pole" is also poor terminology because in fact there is no pole for the field ${\bf B}$, it goes in loops. But the convention is that the end where the field lines point away *outside* the magnet is the "north" so in this example $x$ is the north pole and $y$ the south pole.

Answer (score 0):

The question is referring to the lines of force outside the coil. The lines of force go from the north pole to the south pole outside the magnet. The direction is the opposite inside from south to north.

Hence if you use the right hand rule correctly, you will see that the lines of force so from y to x outside the coil.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't quite understand. If the line of forces go from y to x outside the coil (which I think it's right), then doesn't answer choice A in the picture make sense? Why is the answer B then?

Comment: ?? In your answer you say one thing, then in an added comment you say the exact opposite.